# All records are shown as '0000-00-00', loading dates into mysql from file

Tags: mysql

I have a CSV file with one column with the next data:

```
"2015-01-01",
...
...
"2015-03-27"
```

I created mysql table that way:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_tbl` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `date` DATE NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

I am trying to insert data using the next command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/myFile.csv' INTO TABLE my_tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@col1) set date=@col1;
```

*The problem:* **When checking my_tbl I see that all records are '0000-00-00'**

1. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?
2. Did I define the table as it should be (e.g. Maybe it was better to define timestamp etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Spot the difference:

```
[..snip..] BY '\n' (@col1) set date=@co1;
                       ^---------------^
```

Comment: Tnx Marc. It is a typo in my question. The problem is still the same. @MZ

Comment: try `FIELDS ENCAPSULATED BY '"'`. If you don't tell mysql that `"` is not part of the data, it'll try to parse `"` as part of the field's value, and kill the entire date value - `"`' is not part of a mysql date string.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I should have added **FIELDS ENCLOSED BY  '\"'**. So the LOAD query should be this way:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/myFile.csv' INTO TABLE my_tbl FIELDS ENCLOSED BY  '\"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'   (@col1) set date=@col1;
```

Tnx for user @Marc B for the hint